# Can somebody tell me what effect is this?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

[image: from instagram]

I really liked this editing. What is this called? can somebody tell me please?

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) and edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, too. Thank you!

Comment: Love this concept. Might have to try it myself sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two photographs. One shot with man and stick, second without. Tripod was probably used. Open in Photoshop as 2 layers, with man/stick layer on top. Erase bottom of the man up to the stick, revealing the lower layer.

This could also be achieved by shooting the man/stick in front of (easiest) a blue or green screen (or similar). Trim away what you don't want and paste onto the background image.